# How to view event label and category?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When I go to `Reports > Engagement > Events`, all the event names are shown.

I've setup custom click events which also send an event label and event category. However, these properties don't seem to be accessible.

[image]

How do I access event labels and categories in Google Analytics?

Comment: In `GA4` there are no action, category and label. Are you talking about `Universal Analytics` or `GA4`? if you need them you can create custom dimensions adding to your custom events for example.